# MultiByteToWideChar - и кодировка UTF-16 и размер wchar_t

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот есть WinApi-шная функция: MultiByteToWideChar, которая преобразовывает входной буфер, пусть в данном случае будет UTF-8 в UTF-16.

То есть на вход я подаю массив char`ов в кодировке UTF-8 и соответственно так же подаю массив wchar_t для получения туда результата преобразования, но так как заранее размер массива после преобразования я знать не могу, то у функции предусмотрен вызов с нулевым последним параметром и тогда MultiByteToWideChar вернет кол-во Символов UTF-16, которое будет после преобразование моей строки UTF-8.

И вот чего я не совсем могу понять: UTF-16, как и UTF-8 - это кодировка переменной длинны, только с размером по 2 байта и вот вопрос: а если я на вход подам такой символ, который занимает в UTF-16 Более двух байт, то есть 4 байта ??

Как это все соотносится с размером wchat_t на Виндоус в 2 байта ??

Comment: UTF-16 (точнее UCS-2) - это кодировка фиксированной длины. В UTF-16 символы занимают 2 байта, а символы вне BMP не представимы. Вообще для них как бы есть костыль из суррогатных пар, но к нему не следует прибегать.

Comment: @user7860670, не понимаю. UTF-16 это способ представления Юникода. Если в юникоде есть какие то символы/смайлики - значит UTF-16 должен их, как то кодировать. А значит UTF-16 не может быть кодировкой фиксированной длинны, Вы же сами написали про суррогатные пары, что UTF-16 может расширятся до 4 байт. А вот UTF-32 - это реальная кодировка фиксированной длинны, всегда 4 байта.

Comment: UTF-16 это способ представления юникода, но в том юникоде, который он должен был представлять не было никаких расширений и все прекрасно укладывалось в два байта, даже с запасом. А потом лингвисты просекли, что они могут фармить репу, штампуя предложения по расширению юникода. И пришлось даже добавлять костыль с суррогатными парами. Однако на практике людей, пользующихся, например, древне лидийским языком, нет и выход за пределы BMP говорит о мусоре в данных.

Answer (score 2):

Если Ваш символ нельзя просто так закодировать в 2 байта, то в Windows используются [суррогатные пары](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). То есть, такие символы будут закодированы двумя двубайтовыми элементами.

цитата с википедии

```
Символы же в диапазоне 1000016..10FFFF16 (больше 16 бит) кодируются по следующей схеме:

Из кода символа вычитается 10000. В результате получится значение от нуля до FFFFF, которое помещается в разрядную сетку 20 бит.
Старшие 10 бит (число в диапазоне 0000..03FF) суммируются с D800, и результат идёт в ведущее (первое) слово, которое входит в диапазон D800..DBFF.
Младшие 10 бит (тоже число в диапазоне 0000..03FF) суммируются с DC00, и результат идёт в последующее (второе) слово, которое входит в диапазон DC00..DFFF.
```

Comment: так в это, если я правильно понял, мой и вопрос: если я на вход MultiByteToWideChar подал символ, который нельзя закодировать один wchar_t, какой результат тогда должна выдать мне функция MultiByteToWideChar при предварительном ее вызове ? Если она мне возвратит один 1 символ, то я выделю только 1 wchar_t и символ не поместится. Если вернет 2 символа, то это будет не правда, так как символ один. Вот я и не могу понять.

Comment: Вы путаете символы и их кодировки. суррогатная пара - это способ закодировать  символ. Некоторые символы могут также кодироваться  двумя юникодними точками (unicode point) (например, ё или й). Поэтому, когда говорим о длине строки, нужно уточнять, какую именно длину имеем ввиду. Отвечая на вопрос - функция для такого символа вернет 2. Но это будет один символ. В этом и вся сложность мультибайтовых кодировок